# Пропал сохраненный файл word

Tags: ms-word, восстановление

Я скачала и отредактировала текстовый файл, потом сохранила его и закрыла, думая, что он будет храниться в папке Downloads. Но его нет ни там, ни в Recent Documents, ни в  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ .

Помогите, пожалуйста!

upd: Кажется, удалось найти его с помощью EaseUs Date Recovery, но восстановить не получается, т.к. "не обнаружено предыдущих версий"...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в Word-е нажать **файл - открыть** и посмотреть перечень последних открытых документов. Обычно последние редактируемые файлы там. 
Файл мог сохраниться и в папке темп, а не в Download и имя его может быть другим. 
А раз уже вы занялись восстановлением, то обычно это делается на другом компьютере или путем запуска утилит с внешнего носителя, запись на диск где находился файл нужно минимизировать, результаты сканирования следует сохранять на другой носитель или хотя бы другой раздел диска.